# Typeable Instances for Temporary Types

Tags: haskell, reflection

I am trying to make a reified (using [Data.Reflection](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-1.3.2)) type an instance of Typeable.

```
newtype Zq q = Zq Int
```

I can derive a `Typeable1` instance for `Zq`, but this comes with the implicit constraint `(Typeable q)`. I want to use a value of type `Zq q` in a function which requires the argument to be `Typeable`. So there are a few questions:

1. Is there any way to make a reified type `Typeable`?
2. If not, is there any way to modify the existing library to allow for this?
3. In general, which types *can* be made `Typeable`? It seems that by using `DeriveDataTypeable` and `StandaloneDeriving`, any concrete type I can think of (aside from a temporary type like the reified type) can be an instance.

**EDIT**
Code snippet of what I'm talking about:

```
f = reify (42::Int) (\ (_::Proxy q) ->
  let x = Zq 15 :: Zq q -- x = 15 mod 42
  in ...
```

I would like `Zq q`, where `q` is the *reified* type, to be an instance of `Typeable`. The only way I know to do this is to make `q` `Typeable` as well. Of course, if I reify 42 to `q1` and then reify 43 to `q2`, these should not be equal types. On the other hand, I realize I cannot expect two *different* type variables which reify the same value to have equal TypeReps (even though in practice they are identical).

Comment: Basically everything about Typeable will be changing in GHC 7.8, iirc. That complicates answering questions like these..

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

```
*Main> :t (Zq 42, Zq 42)
(Zq 42, Zq 42) :: (Zq q, Zq q1)
*Main> :t [Zq 42, Zq 42]
[Zq 42, Zq 42] :: [Zq q]
*Main>
```

The elements of the pair have different types, while the elements of the list are natutally of the same type. No surprise here.

If you want to keep it this way, it appears impossible to make `Zq q` typeable. The whole point of `Typeable` is that identical types get identical representations, while distinct types get distinct representations. The whole point of phantom types is just the opposite, to generate a new unique type at every opportunity. The type class mechanism does not support this kind of abuse. We would need a new unique `TypeRep` whenever our value is bound to something with a new type variable, or something like that.

OTOH if you want `Zq q` and `Zq q1` to be convertible to each other even if `q` and `q1` are distinct, you just write an instance of `Typeable (Zq a)` by hand. Make `typeOf` return a `TypeRep` that an automatically generated instance for

```
newtype Zq = Zq Int
```

would return.

Disclaimer: I have no idea what I'm talking about, honest!